# Recommendation for a program to map flood extent?

Tags: gratis, modeling

Given DEM and inflow hydrograph, I am trying to make a map of flood inundation from a dam breach. Does anyone know of a suitable program (free) to model this?

I have tried to model using FLO-2D software, but it is difficult to deal with the output.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What OS must it run on? What specific features do you need? Must it allow for commercial use, or is it personal/educational only?

Comment: Have you considered OpenFOAM?